# Typeorm entities not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'm trying to create a project with typeorm with javascript, a connection works correctly, but typeorm can't find my entities.

I am following the example provided by the type documentation:
https://typeorm.io/#/usage-with-javascript

app.js:

```
typeorm.createConnection({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.MYSQL_IP, // Docker Env
  port: process.env.MYSQL_INTERNAL_PORT,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [
    require('./Model/TestSchema.js'),
  ],
}).then((connection) => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(cors(CorsConfigs));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(authentication);
  app.use(router);

  const testRepository = connection.getRepository('Category');
  const teste = { name: 'TypeScript' };

  app.listen(process.env.BACKEND_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Rodando na porta: ${process.env.BACKEND_PORT.toString()}`);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

Model/TestSchema.js:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Category',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
};
```

the connection is working correctly, the problem and when I run it shows me:

Error: RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Category" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

at new RepositoryNotFoundError (/app/src/error/RepositoryNotFoundError.ts:11:9)

at EntityManager.getRepository (/app/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:919:19)

at Connection.getRepository (/app/src/connection/Connection.ts:346:29)

at /app/src/app.js:32:37

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in

```
entities: [
  require('./Model/TestSchema.js'),
],
```

you need remove the `.js` extension on file path, smt like:

```
entities: [
  require('./Model/TestSchema'),
],
```

Comment: Continues with the same error :(
Is it some configuration of the babel?

Comment: Try adding  some `console.log('test')`  to `./Model/TestSchema` to check if it starts at all

Answer (score 0):

First, anyone who is using TypeOrm with javascript should read [this](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/usage-with-javascript#:%7E:text=Using%20with%20JavaScript%20%2D%20typeorm&text=TypeORM%20can%20be%20used%20not,objects%20with%20all%20required%20metadata.) article once, because in most places documentation is about how to use TypeOrm with typescript not javascript.

Abner, please change your TestSchema.js to this:

```
var EntitySchema = require("typeorm").EntitySchema;

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: "Category", 
  tableName: "Category",
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
});
```